# Não consigo remover background padrão

Tags: css3, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, less

Galera seguinte, estou usando um plugin wordpress para organizar os pratos do cardápio do restaurante, este: (food-and-drink-menu - url: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/food-and-drink-menu/)

Bom, vamos lá!
As configurações do plugin são bem simples e por padrão ele adiciona um background rosa claro, conforme segue a imagem: (http://prntscr.com/k24wzm).
Mas, o fundo do site é outro, eu quero remover este background, tentei várias formas e não consegui, porque no ".css" ele não está.
Como resolvo isso ?

```css
/**
 * CSS Stylesheet for the front-end interface for Food and Drink Menu
 *
 * @package Food and Drink Menu
 */

.fdm-menu.clearfix,
.fdm-menu .clearfix {
 clear: both;
}

.fdm-menu,
.fdm-section {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.fdm-menu,
.fdm-menu>li,
.fdm-section,
.fdm-section>li {
 list-style: none;
}
.fdm-columns-2 .fdm-column {
 width: 47%;
 float: left;
}
.fdm-menu .fdm-column {
 margin: 0 3% 0 0;
}
.fdm-columns-1  .fdm-column {
 margin-right: 0;
}
.fdm-columns-2 .fdm-column-last {
 float: right;
 margin: 0 0 0 3%;
}
.fdm-section-header {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
}
.fdm-section-header,
.fdm-section-header h3,
.fdm-section-header p,
.fdm-item-panel,
.fdm-item-panel p {
 margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.fdm-section-header h3 {
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.fdm-item {
 margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.fdm-item-panel {
 position: relative;
}
.fdm-item-panel p {
 margin: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.fdm-item-panel .fdm-item-title {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.fdm-item-has-image .fdm-item-panel p  {
 padding-left: 35%;
}
.fdm-item-image {
 float: left;
 width: 33%;
 height: auto;
}
.fdm-item-has-price .fdm-item-panel p {
 padding-right: 20%;
}
.fdm-item-price-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20%;
 text-align: right;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.fdm-menu-footer {
 font-size: 85%;
 font-style: italic;
}

/**
 * This media query is pegged to Bootstrap 3's breakpoint
 *
 * Edit the max-width to match your responsive site's collapsed columns
 * breakpoint
 ********************************************************/
@media (max-width: 991px) {

  .fdm-columns-2 .fdm-column {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
 }

}

/**
 * Fully vertical layout for very small screens
 **********************************************/
@media (max-width: 450px) {

 .fdm-item-image {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
 }
 .fdm-item-has-image .fdm-item-panel p,
 .fdm-item-has-price .fdm-item-panel p {
  padding: 0;
 }
 .fdm-item-price-wrapper {
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100%;
 }

}
```

Comment: Cara vc tem um link do projeto? Nas imagens da documentação do plugin não aparece esse fundo rosa não, ele está vindo de outro lugar....

Comment: Você fala do meu site ou do projeto dele ? Se quiser eu passo o link do site: http://cantinafratello.com.br/index.php/cardapio/
olha ai!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que na `linha 173` do seu `style.css` tem esse estilo que esta deixando o background rosa.

```
.content-page ul {
    background: #FFD1D1; /* aqui vc coloca a cor que quiser */
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #900;
}
```

Se vc não puder trocar essa cor, crie uma nova regra de css e inclua nas UL dentro da div `.content-page`

Tipo:

```
.content-page ul.cor {
    background: #minha cor aqui!
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #900;
}
```

Comment: Olá, Hugo fiz o teste em localhost e deu certo... Mas, vou investigar se isso não vai afetar outras classes, ou vou criar outra classse como voce informou...
Obrigado já ajudou muito!

Comment: @DemetriusReis que bom que já funcionou em localhost, confere se a cor não vai mudar em outro lugar e se mudar crie a classe nova e adicione nas UL que precisar que ai não tem erro. Teste direitinho e se resolver o problema considere marcar uma resposta como aceita ✔ , assim a pergunta não fica pendente no site como Pergunta sem Reposta Aceita. Boa sorte com o projeto.

Comment: Feito! Obrigado novamente pelas dicas!

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar `!important` para sobrescrever as prioridades do background.
https://zenorocha.com/css-important/

Verifique na telinha do desenvolvedor do navegador (inspeccionar elemento) qual elemento está aplicando o background e sobrescreva ele.

Comment: vou tentar obrigado!